# What is used for the key in a System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

So, a `System.Windows.Forms.Control` has a `Controls` property of type `Control.ControlCollection`. I have a control on a form that has a bunch of small sub-controls in this collection. These sub-controls have a label and a text identifier that's the field name from a database.

I need to be able to go back into the `Controls` collection and find the controls by name. `ControlCollection` has a `public virtual Control this[string key] { get; }` and a `public virtual bool ContainsKey(string key)`, so it looks like I should be able to look them up.

However, the Add function (`public virtual void Add(Control value)`) doesn't take a key string, just the `System.Windows.Forms.Control` you're adding, and all my calls to `ContainsKey` are returning false.

Figuring something on the `Control` has to be overridden to be the key (since only the `Control` is passed), I tried overriding `ToString()` to return the database field name (which I'm wanting to use for the lookup), but `ContainsKey` still returns false when I know a control for the field specified is present.

The documentation for `this[string key] { get; }` says the key parameter is "The name of the control to retrieve from the control collection." The `Control` does not have a Name property I can override, its only Name property contains the class name, which will be the same for every control I'm adding. The documentation for `ContainsKey(string key)` says the key parameter is "The key to locate", which is even less helpful.

Found the answer, but I already wrote all this up so I might as well publish it and then self-answer in case someone else might find it useful...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While I can't override the `Name` property, it's {get;set;}, not pure {get;} as I stupidly assumed. So if I set the `Name` of my control to the database field name before I add it to the `Controls` collection, I can look it up as expected.

The answer was in the summary docs of the `Control[] Find(string key, bool searchAllChildren)` method, not the docs for the functions I was going to use:
"Searches for controls by their System.Windows.Forms.Control.Name property and builds an array of all the controls that match."

Comment: Thanks for answering your own question. No pun intended!

Comment: What you see in the question is how it went down. Wrote first 3 paragraphs. Thought of ToString thing and tried it. Wrote paragraph 4. Checked the documentation on the functions I'd be using. Wrote paragraph 5. Tripped over the Find docs. Wrote the last paragraph and the answer... :)

Comment: Net result: Lots of "respect points" for being stupid, then not, then not at all :-)

Comment: I must admit I too dug out this detail from the horror dox more than once and always wished I'd made that an SO Q+A for quick reference...